# Some ports in my IP direct to unknown server

Tags: networking, security, linux-networking, network-security

### Backgrounds

I have a dedicated server(which is a desktop) running in my office. It has static IP and was running for about 5 years now with out any network problems. However, after the office had a power outage for a day, I cannot no longer access my server with some ports. (Yes, the server IP did not change and the static IP remained the same)

### Server Specs

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Static IP

### Problem

I can access my server machine with some ports such as following protocols and ports. However with some ports, I cannot connect to my own server. It directs to an unknown server.

#### Ports that direct me to weird place.

- port 80 (Apache): When I try to access my web server, a weird page appears:
  [Weird Web Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7S2d.png)

I am not Chinese nor uses any Chinese devices in my office. As well as not using any webpages related to China. This page was not made by me and never had one like this before as well.

Even if I use Firefox in the server machine itself to access http://127.0.0.1 the same page appears. Also Apache2 failed to bind IP, so I cannot test HTTPS.

- port 22 (FTP): My server uses `vsftpd` however when I try to access my server using FTP it directs to an unknown FTP server. The FTP server is even using `fzSftp` which I never used. Also cannot login to my server as well.

#### Ports that connects to my real server

- SSH
- 8888 (for Jupyter Notebook)
- 5001 (for my API server)

I have no idea what is going on with my network, so I am asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first run `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` to see which process have running ports. Make a copy of that and save it kill the process which are malicious

Also install clamav to run a virusscan.
https://upcloud.com/resources/tutorials/scan-ubuntu-server-malware

And use a firewall like iptables to only allow incoming ports you trust. For now I would recommend to only allow SSH https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-4-block-all-incoming-traffic-but-allow-ssh.html

Comment: While scanning using clamav, I killed processes that were running in port 80. Then I started Apache2, it started running as it should. However, there seems to be a code that is running internally.

Comment: You could some foresic investigation, but I would never trust this machine, so safest is to backup the important files and install a new machine. For forensic tool see here: https://github.com/aquasecurity/tracee?__hstc=&__hssc=&hsCtaTracking=3b98a6a4-e21d-4ba1-bb2d-e4c776697cdf%7Cba1ffb84-f32b-401e-8abe-8d8c14a9c302. Also check the other tools that are listed in the article i provided

Comment: So, it turned out to be that the server got an attack and port 80 and 22 had some process running on which leads to the attacker's server. So, I just backed up some files and wiped it out.

Comment: Awesome good to hear. My tip next time harden it with a CIS baseline